# Assemblyx86 filling an array with user input

Tags: arrays, assembly

i have this part of code in which i am trying to fill an array (named array_number) with users input. For that reason i use a loop. Before the loop i use 
MOV AH, type array_number and because array_number is type SWORD, AH=2.
While i was debuging i saw the inside the loob AH for some reason goes 0 and i can't find out why since the only time i use it inside the loop is for ADD counter2, AH (counter is type BYTE).
Here is the part of code this problem appears, thank you for your time.

```
    mov ECX, table_size ; ECX=8
    mov AH, TYPE array_number ;  type is SWORD so AH=2 
    mov EBX, offset array_number ;
L1:
    mov EDX, OFFSET string1 ; output
    CALL WriteString ; output
    ADD counter, 1d ; output
    MOVZX EAX, counter ; output
    CALL WriteDec ; output
    mov EDX, OFFSET string2 ; output
    CALL WriteString ; output
    CALL ReadDec ; input
    movzx EDI,counter2 ; counter 2 goes like 0...2...4...6
    ADD EBX,EDI ; 
    MOV [EBX], EAX ; fill array
    add counter2, AH ; counter + 2   <------why ah goes 0?
    CALL Crlf
    LOOP L1
```

Edit: for someone who might check it, this one is the correct for array filling.

```
mov ECX, table_size ; ECX=8
    mov EDI, 0d
L1:
    mov EBX, offset array_number ;
    mov EDX, OFFSET string1 ; output
    CALL WriteString ; output
    ADD counter, 1d ; output
    MOVZX EAX, counter ; output
    CALL WriteDec ; output
    mov EDX, OFFSET string2 ; output
    CALL WriteString ; output
    CALL ReadDec ; input
    ADD EBX,EDI ; 
    ADD EDI, type array_number
    MOV [EBX], EAX ; fill array
    CALL Crlf
    LOOP L1
```

Comment: Don't rely on register values being preserved across function calls unless you're certain that they will be. In particular, `eax` (and therefore all its sub-parts `ax`, `ah`, `al`) is typically used to return a result back from a function.

Comment: Now that I look closer at the code I see that you're even explicitly overwriting `eax` without preserving it. So it's to be expected that the value of `ah` changes.

Comment: i didn't know that. thnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AH` is a part of `EAX`. Since you and/or a procedure (`CALL ...`) changed EAX, also AH has been changed.